# multiple conditional databinding on one control or vice versa

Tags: winforms, design-patterns

Winforms question:

Better design to have 1 control, say a dropDownList, conditionally bind to multiple datasources or multiple dropDownLists with each their own datasource?

You'd use if then logic to select which datasource to connect to with the first option.  You'd use if then logic to select which databound control to enable and show() with the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the first one, unless the dropdowns controls themselves were different. It might not be just databinding that changed, colours, styles, event handlers... 
You could deal with them as well of course, but at waht point does it beome too messy.
There is one thing though, if you do all the controls, position them in code when you make them visible, don't lay them one on top of the other in the designer so you don't have to, terrible habit that.

Comment: I took your advise and mapped multiple datasources to one control.  Being finished with the initial version, I can see this option creates much less overhead.  Thanks!